# How to remove duplicates usernames before a splitter in lines?

Tags: notepad++, regex, text-editors, sublime-text-3, text-editing

**I want to remove duplicated usernames in lines before the splitter : and keep only the first line of these usernames.**

**Lines Example:**

```
zzzz:000000zl
zzzz:000000zl!
zzzz:000000zl1
zzzz:000000zl123
zzzz:000000zl69
zzzz:000000zl?
AdSFF12:Sample198445
AdSFF12:Sample198445!
AdSFF12:Sample198445#
AdSFF12:Sample198445$
AdSFF12:Sample1984456
TestOf13:Smpletest1211
TestOf13:Smpletest1211!
TestOf13:Smpletest1211#
TestOf13:Smpletest1211$
TestOf13:Smpletest12112
TestOf13:Smpletest561
TestOf13:Smpletest561!
TestOf13:Smpletest561#
TestOf13:Smpletest561$
TestOf13:Smpletest5612
TestOf13:SmpletestZ2
TestOf13:SmpletestZ2!
TestOf13:SmpletestZ2#
TestOf13:SmpletestZ2$
TestOf13:SmpletestZ23
TestOf13:Smpletestz3qwe
TestOf13:Smpletestz3qwe!
TestOf13:Smpletestz3qwe1
TestOf13:Smpletestz3qwe123
TestOf13:Smpletestz3qwe69
TestOf13:Smpletestz3qwe?
```

**Result Needed:**

```
zzzz:000000zl
AdSFF12:Sample198445
TestOf13:Smpletest1211
```

**Your help will be much appreciated, thank you in advance <3.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `^((.*?:).+\R)(\2.+\R)+`
- Replace with: `$1`
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- **UNCHECK** `. matches newline`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
^       # beginning of line
    (       # start group 1
        (       # start group 2
            .*?     # 0 or more any character but newline, not greedy
            :       # a colon
        )       # end group 2
        .+      # 0 or more any character but newline
        \R      # any kind of linebreak (i.e. \r, \n, \r\n)
    )       # end group 1
    (       # group 3, you can use (?: for non capture group
        \2      # back reference to group 2 (i.e. the part before the colon)
        .+      # 0 or more any character but newline
        \R      # any kind of linebreak (i.e. \r, \n, \r\n)
    )+      # end of group 3, may appear 0 or more times
```

**Replacement:**

```
$1          # content of group 1, the value of the first line
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]

Comment: You are the best Toto can you make a code that works in EmEditor?

i use it for large files and i tried the code in EmEditor and it's not working there 

https://prnt.sc/26whmb1

Comment: @DeathRival: Sorry, I don't know/use EmEditor, May be change `\R` into `[\r\n]`